# Are there deeper conditions in jquery for assigning css values of classes to variables? It doesn't work with all classes I would like

Tags: jquery

It often works to assign as mentioned in title, for example:

```
var a1 = $('.entry--menu .btn.entry--link').css('left');
```

When I execute  `alert(a1)`  it shows me the assigned value of the property `left` of the class `.entry--menu .btn.entry--link`

But there are other cases where it doesn't work, for example:

```
var a2 = $('.last-seen-products .product--box .product--image .image--element').css('width');
```

When I execute `alert(a2)`, it shows `null`.

I tried different things in order to find out why - for example I assigned in the css file at the top the following: `width:100px`
But nothing works.

Is there something that I overlook? Are there requirements, for example something like (a fictitious) requirement that the class must have the property `position:absolute` or something similar??

Comment: Any chance you can make a jsFiddle which outlines the problem? I've never encountered any errors with .css so far if the property was set on the element.

Comment: Perhaps the element you're targeting in the second doesn't have css width set, but max-width or inline html width?

Comment: Can you include `html`, `css` at Question?

Comment: `var a2 = $('.last-seen-products .product--box .product--image .image--element').css('width');` which class contains the definition of width that apply to the elements these contain that classes? is there more than one defining it?

Answer (score 0):

it "works" for me if you separate the classes by ","

```
var a2 = $('.last-seen-products, .product--box, .product--image, .image--element').css('width');
```

but it returns the last value it founds in the last class where it founds it... I mean if:

```
.last-seen-products{ width: 100px; }
.image--element{ width: 10px }
.product--image{ width: 500px }
```

it will return "10px" because is the last class in the list... hope it helps.